# FORTRAN 77 - packing 8 a1 characters into an integer*8

Tags: fortran

An odd issue here. I am converting legacy F77 code that packed 8 a1 characters into a 64 bit integer, and the code worked back in the day. But in today's world to get 8 characters in a word I need to move to integer*8 variables, and the code is failing in that case. It works until it's packed 4 characters, but character 5 simply rotates around and overwrites the first packed character. Here is a sample output for "hello world”, of note is that the integer*8 variable OUTBUF suddenly shrinks and appears to convert to an integer*4 variable too:

```
    hello world
in='hello world                                                             '
cn= 8,k=1,j='h',outbuf(k)='h       '
cn=16,k=1,j='e',outbuf(k)='he      '
cn=24,k=1,j='l',outbuf(k)='hel     '
cn=32,k=1,j='l',outbuf(k)='hell'
cn=40,k=1,j='o',outbuf(k)='oell'
 # SPACE
cn= 8,k=2,j='w',outbuf(k)='w       '
cn=16,k=2,j='o',outbuf(k)='wo      '
cn=24,k=2,j='r',outbuf(k)='wor     '
cn=32,k=2,j='l',outbuf(k)='worl'
cn=40,k=2,j='d',outbuf(k)='dorl'
 # SPACE
```

I've distilled the code to this snippet, anyone know F77 anymore and see what’s happening?  thanks.

```
          program cow

      implicit integer*8 (a-z)
      integer inbuf(72)
      integer*8 outbuf(40)
```

c         changing the integer*1 to integer*8 fixes the problem !!!!!!!!!

```
      integer*1 j

      read 99, inbuf
99    FORMAT(BZ,72a1)
      print 1, inbuf
 1    format("in='",72a1,"'")

      IP=0
      k = 1

      DO 100 I=1,40
         OUTBUF(I)= 8H
 100  CONTINUE

 200  IP=IP+1
      IF(IP.GT.72) GO TO 6000
      J= INBUF(IP)
      IF(J.EQ." ") GO TO 6000
      CN = (MOD(CP,8)+1) * 8
      outbuf(k) = outbuf(k) .and. (.not. lshift('377'O, (cn-8)))
      OUTBUF(K) = OUTBUF(K) .OR. lSHiFT( j,(CN-8))
      print 4301, cn, k, j, outbuf(k)
 4301 format("cn=",i2,",k=",i1,",j='",a1,"',outbuf(k)='",a8,"'")
      CP=CP+1
      GO TO 200

 6000 continue
      print *,'# SPACE'
      call exit
      end
```

Note that this code is for little endian machines.

Comment: Can't you just use `CHARACTER`?

Comment: Also, a smaller program would help, this is a very ugly Spaghetti code full of `goto`s.

Comment: Yes the code is ugly ... straight from the original 1970's source. The idea is to take one a1 character, shift it the appropriate number of bits and AND it into outbuf.  Then compute a new shift count, take the second character and shift it over, AND it in, etc.  It should work for 8 characters but there is something I am missing after 4 characters.  The program will run as is, just type 'hello world' to see it in action. These input characters need to be left-justified in a 64-bit word as they are compared to an existing database of variables, all of which are left-justified.

Comment: Try implicit integer*8 and take care of the integer literals too, but I am not going to try to decypher it.

Comment: What is the internal representation of CHARACTER?  Probably has metadata associated with it and hence would not work, as these data are required to be Integers.

Comment: Character is just a sequence of bytes. The conversuon rules may complicate something, but not too much.

Comment: OK, no more Spaghetti.  It reads a line of A1 characters.  Then sets outbuf to all spaces.  The mainloop fetches a single character, computes a shift count CN, masks out the appropriate 8 bits of outbuf and ORs in the shifted character.  If you type in "hello" the first 4 chars work, the 5 overwrites the first for some unknown reasons

Comment: Actually, it is NOT posssible to compile your code by most of the compilers. It is very far from standard FORTRAN 77. You cannot use logical operators on integers in standard Fortran. You must use bitwise intrinsic functions.

Comment: So I ask again how does one pack 8 a1 characters into an integer*8 variable ... in F77, and forgetting the sample code as a distraction. Apologies for this old brain not seeing a way to do that!

Comment: If you want really FORTRAN77, start with removing .and. .or. .not. lshift() and by adding iadd() ior() not() and ishft(). I cannot compile your code, because my compiler compiles Fortran.

Comment: Integer*8 is a non-standard extension, by the way.

Comment: Thanks you two for your valuable input, I do appreciate it. FORTRAN is so varied I did not realize that integer*8 is non-standard.  I will try using bitwise functions rather than .and., etc.  Come to think of it, the original hardware was 1's compliment and I believe Intel is two's compliment .. will have to ponder those ramifications.  Thanks,

Comment: `Integer*8` is the VERY least problem you have. I would ignore the non-standardness of that for now. It is extremely widely supported.

Comment: If you **really** need F77, you cannot use `NOT`, `IAND` etc - these were only added in Fortran 90, the same time as `TRANSFER`.  Of course, there was [MIL-STD 1753](http://www.fortran.com/mil_std_1753.html), but that was an extension to Fortran 77.

Comment: Which platform is this actually for?  z/OS with VS FORTRAN?  This is about the only relevant Fortran 77-only platform that I can think of.

Comment: I'm converting to Linux, happens to be CentOS 6.x, using pgf77. I fixed the immediate problem., which was using integer*1 for J.  Changing to integer*8 makes the sample code handle >4 characters, it was the shift that was clobbering J.

Answer (score 1):

> " So ignore the code, the task at hand - in FORTRAN 77 - is to pack 8
>   a1 characters into an integer*8 variable. "

Ok, but I will have to wash my hands after this:

```
INTEGER*8  i
CHARACTER*8  ch

EQUIVALENCE (i, ch)

ch = "abcdefgh"
```

Of course, transfer is nicer, but certainly not FORTRAN 77.

Comment: This is not standarf Fortran 77.  To quote from the [F77 standard](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-17.html#sh-17.1); "17.3 Events That Caused Entities to Become Undefined [...] 2. When an entity of a given type becomes defined, all totally associated entities of different type become undefined. ". By defining ch, you are setting i to an undefined value.  This may work, but is liable to break when upgrading a compiler.

Comment: Of course it depends on many assumptions. The transfer however will have similar problems. You have to assume the internal representation of the bit patterns in of integer and character.

Comment: I think it may be time to define a dusty-deck tag, for conversion of really old programs (often Fortran, but also other languages) to something more modern.

Comment: Actually, a compiler might decide to remove the assignment based on the Fortran typing rules.  See all the problems that D1MACH.F causes, which uses similar type punning.

Comment: Nothing in the OP question indicates he is concerned about standards conformance or about portabity  to every obscure compiler there might be.  I would use `equivalence` and include a test using `ibits` to verify it is doing what you expect.  (Yes I know `ibits` is not f77 )

Answer (score 0):

This is quite horrible code to do something trivial in newer Fortran
(since F77...).

You can replace the whole routine by something like

```
  integer, parameter :: llen=72
  character(len=llen) inbuf
  character(len=llen) output
  integer :: i,k
  read (*,'(BZ,A)') outbuf
  k = 1
  do i=1,llen
    if (inbuf(i) /= ' ') then
       outbuf(k) = inbuf(i)
       if (mod(k,8) == 0) then
           ! Some output goes here
       endif 
       k = k + 1
    end if
 end do
```

Comment: And it's trivial in Perl and Objective-C too.  So it was evidently a mistake to post the existing code ... better to simply have asked the question :) So ignore the code, the task at hand - in FORTRAN 77 - is to pack 8 a1 characters into an integer*8 variable.  I'd love to do it a new way, but I cannot think of how to do that!

Comment: To what purpose?  If your purpose is to have a running program, it is better to rewrite it using characters.

Comment: 10,000 + lines of code - avoiding re-write is key :)  User input is compared against a DB of 8H strings stored as integers .... the original code in the 1970s ran on a machine with an integer word size of 64-bits.  Took decades to make that mainstream, but I have to use integer*8 variables to get 8 characters per word.  If I can simply figure out how to pack 8 characters per integer*8 word in modern F77 that would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the second answer; **not** preferred, it is really better to rewrite the program using characters.

Caveat: integer*8 is non-standard.

```
program main
  character(len=8) :: c
  integer*8 output(10)
  c = "12345678"
  call foo(output,10,c)
  write (*,'(Z16)') output(1)
end program main

subroutine foo(a,n,b)
  integer*8 :: a(1)
  character(len=8) :: b

  a(1) = transfer(b,mold=a(1))
end subroutine foo
```

Comment: It depends on the asker, which language he needs. There definitely are platforms, where F77 makes sense. It does warrant at least a sentence commenting you are using a different language than it was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, this input parser took Hollerith data and compared it against Hollerith data in a database, in a case-insensitive manner. The code was written for 60-64 bit, big-endian machines, and used hardware specific shifts, masks, ANDs and ORs to pack the A1 input characters into an A8 INTEGER word for comparison against the database.

And although I did manage to adjust all those shifts, masks and bitwise operations to work on 64-bit little-endian machines (x86_64), it was a PITA, and only worked with pgf77 and ifort, gfortran was having none of that crap!  So this is what I came up with, much nicer, hardware independent, and works on all the compilers available to me:

- The parser still accepts A1 input characters stored in INTEGERs (80a1), and returns packed A8 characters in INTEGER*8 words, for backwards compatibility.
- It converts 80a1 input data to CHARACTER*80 variable IN0:

  ```
    write( in0, '80a1' ) (inbuf(i), i=1,80)
  ```
- Since this is all ASCII data, I used this code to lower-case everything in IN0 to a new character*80 variable IN:

  ```
    do i = 1, len(in0)
    #if (! defined __GFORTRAN__)
        j = ichar(in0(i:i))
        if (j>= ichar("A") .and. j<=ichar("Z") ) then
           in(i:i) = char(ichar(in0(i:i))+32)
        else
             in(i:i) = in0(i:i)
        end if
    #else
        j = iachar(in0(i:i))
        if (j>= iachar("A") .and. j<=iachar("Z") ) then
           in(i:i) = achar(iachar(in0(i:i))+32)
        else
             in(i:i) = in0(i:i)
        end if
    #endif
    end do
  ```
- It was then a simple matter to loop through the CHARACTER*80 variable IN, collect non-space characters into the character variable WORD, and then encode them into INTEGER*8 array OUTBUF:

  ```
    read( word(1:8), ‘a8' ) outbuf(outbufc)
  ```

Thanks all.

Comment: Why you created a new identity? Can you improve the formatting of your post? Why you use a different version for gfortran?

Comment: Apparently I have two IDs with the same name - go figure!  I picked one and hoped for the best, but I am new to SO so apologies. It was formatted properly in the preview ... will try to improve on formatting again. As for gfortran, that compiler wasn't even in the equation when I made the initial post, I was using pgf77.  The drawback to pgf77 and fort is that they cost money, so gfortran provided a compiler that was free.